# Purpose of the [fuel] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

When I came across the [fuel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel) tag, I assumed it related to automotive fuel, like finding diesel stations, or about fuel pre-purchase options for rental cars. The actual questions tagged are rather different:

- Two about purchasing fuel for camp stoves
- One about an airline fuel surcharge
- One (closed) about refueling a private plane
- One (closed) about the best day and time to buy gasoline/petrol in Germany

I don't see any merit in repurposing [fuel] to serve any of its existing uses. Should it be deleted? I could not find any suitable synonyms to propose. [gasoline](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gasoline) is a synonym of [automobiles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automobiles), and there are no questions tagged as [petrol](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petrol) or [diesel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can safely be burninated. I just removed it from all the questions.

Thanks for bringing this up.